# How to post array data to endpoint - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a set of data that I have to send to an endpoint to receive the data and store in my firebase database. When I post my data to the endpoint, the data isn't stored in my DB. I believe I am not submitting the data correctly. I am using **Guzzle**.

What could I be doing wrong? Am I submitting the data `HospitalData` the right way to my endpoint?

**Controller**

```php
// Data to be submitted 
$HospitalData[] = [               
    'patient' => $patient,
    'company' => $companyId,                 
];

Patient::saveInfo($HospitalData);
```

**Patient Model**

```php
public function saveInfo($data)
{
    $url = "endPointUrl";
    $client = new Client();
    $myBody['patient_info'] = json_encode($data);
    $request = $client->post($url, ['form_params' => $myBody]);
    $response = $request->getBody();

    return $response;
}
```

**EndURL**

```php
$patient_info = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$patient_info = $patient_info->patient_info;

foreach($patient_info as $info) 
{
    $data[] = '("'.$info->company.'", "'.$info->patient.'"')';
}

$query = 'INSERT INTO db (`company`,`patient`) VALUES '.implode(',', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this block

```
$HospitalData[] = [               
                    'patient' => $patient,
                     'company' => $companyId,                 
                   ];
```

Should be

```
$HospitalData = [               
                    'patient' => $patient,
                     'company' => $companyId,                 
                   ];
```

Comment: Data is still not saved

Comment: We need some more data. 
- does `$patient_info` have a value after then `json_decode`?
- does the `foreach` block execute?
- what is the value of `$query` ?